# How to write table data from website to CSV through web scraping

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, html-table, beautifulsoup

I am newbie to web scraping I am trying to **scrape** a table data from website after login. I wish to multiply  2nd column by 10.

Currently the table is writing to csv but what I actually want to work is to multiply 2nd column by 10 and write to csv

What I have tried is:

```
r2=session.post("http://www.example.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, "html.parser")
        csvFile=open('Table.csv','w')
        output = csv.writer(csvFile)
        for table in soup.find_all('table')[5:]:
            for row in table.find_all('tr'):
                col = map(cell_text, row.find_all(re.compile('t[dh]')))
                output.writerow(col)
            output.writerow([])
        csvFile.close()
```

For example if I have a table with data in website as:

```
Time    Pressure   Mass     Temp

0.00    1.01       21       23.09
1.00    2.0908     21.1      10.07
2.0     2.8666     22.3      13.6
0.555   2.6545     2.4       32.56

The data for writing csv file should be:



0.00    10.1       21       23.09
1.00    20.908     21.1      10.07
2.0     28.666     22.3      13.6
0.555   26.545     2.4       32.56
```

How to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its depends on how the elements are placed, here i have solution that you can apply it on csv.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Table.csv")
df.Pressure = df.Pressure * 10
df.to_csv("Table_Updated.csv",index=False)
df.to_csv("DataExport.csv",index=False,header=False) # Store without header
```

Comment: .How to write directly from html table instead from csv file?

Comment: You can create data frame before writing it to csv, do post processing and write it on csv.  I have added sample over here. [link](https://github.com/dhamodharanrk/stackoverflow/tree/master/Table%20Scrapping)

Comment: I have updated my requirement. I don't want to write heading into csv. How it is possible to multipy 2nd column by 10 without writing heading?

Comment: are you referring table extraction ? if so you can ignore the column while creating Dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame(table_data[1:],columns=table_data[0])` to `df = pd.DataFrame(table_data[1:])`

Comment: It is not working , heading also still  writing to csv. I dont want heading to write in csv, only values.

Comment: Updated the answer, you can use header=False  while exporting in pandas